# Why json content is not being output in ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am trying to fetch json data from a page to another page.

### js_page.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.get('php_page.php', function(data){

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            alert(data[i]);
        };
    }, 'json');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If i set the page content of php_page.php without any html it is working.

### php_page.php

```
<?php

 echo $name = json_encode(array('myname', 'myage'));
```

But if i put that code inside of an html content js_page.php not outputting anything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
   <?php

     echo $name = json_encode(array('myname', 'myage'));
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Why is that and how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe because you are mixing server side code with client side.

Comment: Because `php_page.php` returns HTML and you are telling `$.get()` to expect json. `$.get()` has no way of knowing which parts of your HTML is JSON.

Comment: you to get the response from php page only. You cant make it with php inside hmtl tags

Comment: @Jim what if i change content type of php_page.php to "application/json" ? i still don't get anything

Comment: works fine here  http://codepad.viper-7.com/KbQFEg

Comment: @user1906399 The content type of PHP page isn't "application/json" you are outputting an HTML page.

Comment: @Jim what i mean is if i put <?php header('content-type: application/json'); ?> at the top of php_page.php, what will happen?

Comment: "what will happen" if you are also sending the html, then all that will happen is you will be sending an incorrect header, and your javascript will still fail. The key question here is why do you want to send this html in the first place?

Comment: @user1906399 It will still fail. You are sending HTML. HTML cannot be parsed as JSON. If I have a text document and save it as a PNG I wont be able to look at it as a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put the JSON inside HTML tags.  Your first version of `php_page.php` is correct.

Comment: if i change the content type of php_page.php using header function , like header('content-type: application/json') at the top of the page, i still don't get anything in js_page.php

Comment: @user1906399 you can set the content type header to `'content-type:fluffyrabbits'` if you like - you will still be sending html mixed with json, which is useless. **why** do you want to do this, it doesnt make any sense what so ever